# Open a child process (adb) in Python 2.7 and interact with it repeatedly without terminating it

Tags: android, python, windows, python-2.7

The internet is telling me over and over to use subprocess.Popen and the communicate() method to read and write stdin and stdout of a child process; but the documentation for communicate() says that it waits for the program to terminate. I am attempting to use adb shell to turn on and off video recording on a phone's camera. I would like to have the adb shell process open already, attached to the device, instead of connecting every time I run it.
This doesn't work:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> adb = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> adb.stdin.write('ls/n')
>>> adb.stdout.read()
```

nor does this:

```
>>> adb = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> adb.communicate(input=b'ls')
```

Both hang. This command runs as expected in a terminal:

```
adb shell ls
```

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit, Python 2.7.13.
I also read about pexpect, but its spawn class does not work on Windows.
So my question is *how* I can create and repeatedly communicate with a child process from Python 2.7 on Windows.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell shell_command
```

This opens starts a remote shell, executes the shell_command and exits the remote shell.

To accomplish the same using python:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> adb = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell", "ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out, err = adb.communicate()
```

If you only want to know if the command returns non-zero return code:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_call(["adb", "shell", "ls"])
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't only want to know the return code, actually. I would like to know how I can open and repeatedly communicate with a child process. I haven't tested yet myself, but I have read that adb shell works faster in interactive mode; i.e., it doesn't have to restart a process every time you send a command. I don't know if it'll be faster by keeping it open, but I know it's too slow as it is. If I wanted to run a one-time process and gather its input when it closed, I could already do that with os.system. The subprocess description offers stdin, but I don't see anyone using it.